# Read binary 16bit streamfile and write to 16bit PGM (C++)

Tags: c++, binary, pgm

this is my first Post as I came along with using the search function so far. But now I wasted a whole day on the following issue:

I recorded a 12bit (written as 16bit) grayscale video and wrote it directly into a binary stream-file (no headers or such).

Now the task is to read the file and output every frame as a 16bit pgm.

The following snipped illustrates what i tried. The output is a valid pgm, but whith "white noise on it".

```
    ...
    imageBufferShort = new short[imageWidth*imageHeight* sizeof(short)];
    ...
    streamFileHandle.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(imageBufferShort),2*imageWidth*imageHeight); //double amount because 8bit chars!
    // As .read only takes chars, I thought, that I just read the double amount of char-bytes and when it is interpreted as short (=16bit) everything is ok?!?

    ...now the pgm output:

    std::ofstream f_hnd(fileName,std::ios_base::out |std::ios_base::binary |std::ios_base::trunc);
    // write simple header
    f_hnd.write("P5\n",3);
    f_hnd << imageWidth << " " << imageHeight << "\n4095\n";  //4095 should tell the pgm to use 2 bytes for each pixel

    f_hnd.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(imageBufferShort),2*imageWidth*imageHeight);
    f_hnd.close();
```

Again, the file is produced and viewable but contains rubbish. Is the initial guess ok? read 2 "chars" and handle them as one "short"? I also trieb a whitespace after every line but this changes nothing, so I decided to post this shorter code.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you make sure that the input is noise-free?

Comment: Also, if you use `new`, you don't need to multiply by sizeof(T). This does not affect correctness though.

Comment: Finally, make sure that your system's [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) matches the input endianness.

Comment: @Domi All good guesses, I'd bet on *endianness*.

Comment: Note that the PGM P5 format, for maxval greater than 255, requires that you send two bytes per pixel, _most significant byte_ first (aka. _big endian_).  Most computers these days are _little endian_, so that means you might have to swap pairs of bytes between input and output.  (PGM docs:  http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html )

Comment: All right. I try this on monday and will report the success :-)

Answer (score 1):

As @Domi and @JoeZ pointed out: Your endianness is probably screwed up. Meaning, the order of your bytes is wrong.

To fix your problem, you will have to iterate over every pixel and swap it's bytes before writing it back to file.

Comment: Ok. Thanks very much. I've never came across the endian-thing. I'll try that on monday and report.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. Thank you all very much. The Endianess was indeed the Problem. The solution is given below:

```
    f_hnd << "P5" << " " << imDimensions.GetWidth() << " " << imDimensions.GetHeight() << " " << "4095\n";

    // convert imageBufferShort to Big-Endian format
    unsigned short imageBufferShortBigEndian[imDimensions.GetWidth()*imDimensions.GetHeight()];

    for (int k=0 ; k<imDimensions.GetWidth()*imDimensions.GetHeight() ; k++)
    {
        imageBufferShortBigEndian[k] = ( (imageBufferShort[k] << 8) | (imageBufferShort[k] >> 8) );
    }

    f_hnd.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(imageBufferShortBigEndian),2*imDimensions.GetWidth()*imDimensions.GetHeight());
    f_hnd.close();
```

imageBufferShort has also to an unsigned short-array. If signed types are used, the bitshift-conversion gets slightly more difficult.

Thanks again!